# JavaScript is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<html>
<head> 
<script language="javascript">
$('.go-btn').click(function() {
var color1 = $("#color1").val();
 var color2 = $("#color2").val();
if (color1 == "Blue" && color2 == "Red") {
   alert("Just like the sky!");
}
else {
 alert("Suit yourself then...");
 }
})
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Favorite Color</h3>
<select id="color1">
<option name="fav_color3" value="Blue"> Blue 
<br /></option>
<option name="fav_color3" value="Green"> Green 
<br /></option>
</select>



<h3>Favorite Color</h3>
<select id="color2">
<option name="fav_color3" value="Black"> Black 
<br /></option>
<option name="fav_color3" value="Red"> Red <br 
/></option>
</select>
<button class="go-btn" >
 go</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Their is something wrong with the script i cant seem to figure it out.. i can display the select option and the go button its only the script that is not working please help

Comment: have you any errors in your console?

Comment: You have used `jQuery` library.. so add it to your html

Comment: no there is no error its just the script is running i dont know why

Comment: @user3551191: If your page is like it is above, yes there *is* an error in the console. Specifically: `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Answer (score 2):

This is probably because the code evaluates before the button exists. Either move JS to the bottom or wrap it like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    // your code goes here
});
</script>
```

**EDIT** Yeah, plus you have to include jQuery.

Comment: missed to add jQuery library.

Comment: @Praveen Thanks, I've missed that.

Answer (score 1):

Forgot to add jquery lib and document.ready function in jquery

```
<html>
    <head> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(function(){
    $('.go-btn').click(function() {
    var color1 = $("#color1").val();
     var color2 = $("#color2").val();
    if (color1 == "Blue" && color2 == "Red") {
       alert("Just like the sky!");
    }
    else {
     alert("Suit yourself then...");
     }
    })
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h3>Favorite Color</h3>
    <select id="color1">
    <option name="fav_color3" value="Blue"> Blue 
    <br /></option>
    <option name="fav_color3" value="Green"> Green 
    <br /></option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery (it looks like) in your javascript code.  You must therefore load the jQuery library first in the `head`.

e.g.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery and its not in the head or the body...

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Add that...

And then wrap your click event in a document.ready or

```
$(function() {
  //click event
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using jquery codes but yu haven't added Jquery Library. It is advised to use latest version of jquery. You  you can add Jquery Library to your codes like that:

```
<html>
<head> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript">
$('.go-btn').click(function() {
...
</script>
```

Link in the `"<script src="` provide you to use the latest version of Jquery.